# WPF TabItems have no parent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, tabcontrol

I create TabItems via a binding and try to access the `parent TabControl` in `TabItemDrop`.
However, in the case of a drop event the parent from the source is always `null`. If I create the TabItems myself it works though.

**.xaml**:

```
<TabControl ItemSource="{Binding TabItemList}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItemPreviewMouseMove" />
            <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItemDrop" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Header}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Body}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Code Behind (**.xaml.cs**):

```
private void TabItemDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TabItem tabItem = e.Source as TabItem;
    if(tabItem.Parnent == null){
        //Always null, expect to get the tabControl here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FrameworkElement.Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent) points to the logical parent of the control. Once you're binding ItemsSource property of the TabControl to data objects, the TabControl generates item container controls (TabItem) that visualizes the data elements. In this case each container control (TabItem) is not being logical child of the TabControl; it is visual child though.

In order to get the parent TabControl (in any case), traverse through visual tree, e.g.:

```
private void TabItemDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TabItem tabItem = e.Source as TabItem;

    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tabItem);

    while (parent != null)
    {
        if (parent is TabControl)
        {
            break;
        }

        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }

    if (parent != null)
    {
        //Got the tabControl here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's! Worked pretty well :)

Answer (score 1):

@Bgorski described everything correctly.
But I want to offer another way of solutions.
You can set the binding in the Tag property in XAML (this is a fallback property) and then retrieve the value from this property.

ElementName type binding example:

```
    <TabControl x:Name="tab" ItemsSource="{Binding TabItemList}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItemPreviewMouseMove" />
                <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItemDrop" />
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding ElementName=tab}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

FindAncestor type binding example:

```
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItemList}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItemPreviewMouseMove" />
                <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItemDrop" />
                <Setter Property="Tag"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Retrieving the value:

```
    private void TabItemDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem tabItem = e.Source as TabItem;
        TabControl tab = tabItem.Tag as TabControl;
        if (tab != null)
        {
            //Expect to get the tabControl here
        }
    }
```